# Items moving upwards when I use the :hover in css (No javascript)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create an effect without JavaScript, that when your mouse hovers over the image, where an image enlarges, gets a shadow, then has a transparent `div` with text inside comes down from the top of the image.

```css
#note {
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform .3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: -o-transform .3s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: -ms-transform .3s ease-out;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease-in-out, transform .3s ease-out;
  width: 125px;
  height: 175px;
}

#note:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 12px 18px 53px 0 rgba(148, 138, 148, 0.81);
  -moz-box-shadow: 12px 18px 53px 0 rgba(148, 138, 148, 0.81);
  box-shadow: 12px 18px 53px 0 rgba(148, 138, 148, 0.81);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.3);
  -o-transform: scale(1.3);
  transform: scale(1.3);
  width: 125px;
  display: block;
  width: 125px;
  height: 175px;
}

#box1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: 15px;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#text1 {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#note:hover #text1 {
  opacity: 1;
}

#over {
  background-color: grey;
  position: relative;
  top: 89px;
  left: -7px;
  width: 125px;
  height: 176px;
}
```

```html
<div id="note">
  <img src="http://www.simpleimageresizer.com/_uploads/photos/b8804940/Chick_Pea_Wrap_1_125x175.jpg">
  <div id="box1">
    <div id="over"></div>
    <div id="text1">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris at lacus leo. Fusce tempus eleifend ligula at bibendum. Proin lacus.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you need any more info, please ask. I have searched wide and far for an answer to this question but seems I am new to code I do not know what keywords to type in. Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: You mean from the top to cover it?

Comment: Yes, I do. Thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example that accomplishes what you're asking. I adjusted your HTML and added the necessary CSS and marked the styles `/* Added */`. I generally just added some positioning to your text container and added another property into the animation.

```css
#note {
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform .3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: -o-transform .3s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: -ms-transform .3s ease-out;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease-in-out, transform .3s ease-out;
  width: 125px;
  height: 175px;
  overflow: hidden; /* Added */
  position: relative; /* Added */
}

#note:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 12px 18px 53px 0 rgba(148, 138, 148, 0.81);
  -moz-box-shadow: 12px 18px 53px 0 rgba(148, 138, 148, 0.81);
  box-shadow: 12px 18px 53px 0 rgba(148, 138, 148, 0.81);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.3);
  -o-transform: scale(1.3);
  transform: scale(1.3);
  display: block;
  width: 125px;
  height: 175px;
}

#text1 {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  padding: 10px; /* Added */
  width: 125px; /* Added */
  height: 175px; /* Added */
  position: absolute; /* Added */
  bottom: 100%; /* Added */
  left: 0px; /* Added */
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Added */
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* Added */
  box-sizing: border-box; /* Added */
}

#note:hover #text1 {
  opacity: 1;
  bottom: 0px; /* Added */
}
```

```html
<div id="note">
  <img src="http://www.simpleimageresizer.com/_uploads/photos/b8804940/Chick_Pea_Wrap_1_125x175.jpg">
  <div id="text1">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```